# SSMS IP address changes after disconnecting from Azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

We are connecting to Azure SQL server for our work through SSMS. We are whitelisting all the developers IP in Networking section of Azure SQL Server. Whenever we close SSMS connection all the time SSMS IP get changes. Then we need to go and update the new IP in Azure portal. Why SSMS changes the IP all the time. Any solution for this in SSMS settings.

Comment: SSMS doesn't have an IP, the PC it's on does.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP is properly providing you a dynamic IP. You can check your egress IP with a lot of online IP discover services. If it changes overnight/day e.g. https://wtfismyip.com/

To avoid dealing with IP Whitelists you could use a VPN Gateway or Express Route to tunnle your Devs to an Azure VNET and connect the Azure SQL DB with private Link into that VNET.

Alternatively, you could use a Bastion host to run SSMS there.

But in the End, there is nothing which you or Microsoft can do on Azure Side to prevent your client IP from changing when your ISP doesn't provide you a static IP.
Of course, you can ask them to upgrade your internet to a static IP address, or do you use multiple egress IPs in your company? In this case maybe speak with your network admin to get all egress IPs and whitelist those.